# Сместить начало координат в консоли, windows.h

Tags: c++

Есть такая задача, нарисовать в консоли график функции, при попытки что-то нарисовать, получается что изначально координатные оси идут из верхнего левого угла, как сделать так чтобы координатные оси выходили из центра консоли в привычных направлениях?

```
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
HPEN hpen1;
HGDIOBJ hpenOld, hbrushOld;
HBRUSH hbrush;

hpen1 = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(102, 0, 255));
hpenOld = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, hpen1);

MoveToEx(hdc, 50, 50, NULL);
LineTo(hdc, 600, 600);
SelectObject(hdc, hpenOld);
DeleteObject(hpen1);    
}
```

[image: то на чем я остановился]

Comment: просто добавьте половину размера экрана. всех то делов.

Comment: а собственно говоря, как?

Comment: На чужих окнах нельзя рисовать.

Comment: используйте https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclientrect